# Modify the height and length of a form box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the following page:
http://jsfiddle.net/mocfvg4w/17/

But I cannot work out how to decrease the height of the form and increase the length of the box?

I want to be able to make the height slightly smaller and the box at least double the length.

The code I have made is:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="form-holder">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4HDC0Vs.jpg" alt="header" width="500" height="906">
        <form id="form" action="#" method="post" name="result" style="width:200px;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="id" id="input_field" maxlength="4" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  margin-left:-25px;
  width:104px;
  height:142px;
}

.form-holder {
  position: relative;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#input_field").keyup(function(){
 if($(this).val().length == 4 && $(this).val() == "2000") {
     alert("it works");
    // $('#form')
     //     .submit();
 }
 })
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but for sure your HTML markup isn't valid

Comment: Both your html and CSS are invalid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you write css code in wrong way 
replace your css code with below code and you will see the impact

```js
$("#input_field").keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val().length == 4 && $(this).val() == "2000") {
         alert("it works");
        // $('#form')
         //     .submit();
     }
 })
```

```css
form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px;
}

form > input#input_field {
    width:200px;
}

.form-holder {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="form-holder">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4HDC0Vs.jpg" alt="header" width="500" height="906">
        <form id="form" action="#" method="post" name="result">
<td>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="input_field" maxlength="200"/>
</td>
</form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You think this html mark up is valid?

Comment: It's not, but at least the CSS is.

Comment: Thanks, running the code snippet shows the form box but the input field is still the same size, how would I keep both the same size?

Answer (score 0):

you are making a big mistake in your css so its not working because for form dimensions(width, height) you have to mention proper values in px, % ,em ..etc according to your preference..

and also remove style tag from html form where you have mentioned width: 200px; for css width to work..

replace this code..

```
width="104" height="142";
```

with this..

```
width="104px" height="142px";
```